# Can't view database structure via pgAdmin, while psql works ok

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a PostgreSQL database. I can connect to it via psql no problem, however, when I do database listing:

```
my_database=>\l
```

there is no my_database in the list!

When I connect to this same database via pgAdmin, I don't see it in the server's database list too and as an effect, can't view/edit it structure.

What it wrong there?

Comment: May be, the problem is in the rights to access databases from hosts. Check out your pg_hba.conf file.